# Capistrano deploy slow due to assets - .sprockets-manifest*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When deploying our API (which doesn't use assets at all), it hangs for about 5 minutes on this line:

```
DEBUG [985661f8]    cannot access /var/www/api.staging/releases/20160208111413/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest*
DEBUG [985661f8]    : No such file or directory
```

We have already disabled assets in config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

What else needs to be done? We're using these versions:

- capistrano (3.4.0)
- capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
- capistrano-rails (1.1.3)
- capistrano-rails-collection (0.0.3)

Capistrano log:

```
INFO [42c93c96] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.0@appyapi.staging do bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@139.162.4.97
DEBUG [42c93c96] Command: cd /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856 && ( RAILS_ENV=staging /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.0@appyapi.staging do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
INFO [42c93c96] Finished in 279.004 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [f2410fde] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@139.162.4.97
DEBUG [f2410fde] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [f2410fde] Finished in 0.081 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [fd9b639a] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856/assets_manifest_backup as deploy@139.162.4.97
DEBUG [fd9b639a] Command: cd /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856 && /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856/assets_manifest_backup
INFO [fd9b639a] Finished in 0.078 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [462a5734] Running /usr/bin/env ls /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest* as deploy@139.162.4.97
DEBUG [462a5734] Command: cd /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856 && /usr/bin/env ls /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest*
DEBUG [462a5734]    ls: cannot access /var/www/appyapi.staging/releases/20160223041856/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest*
DEBUG [462a5734]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [462a5734] Finished in 0.079 seconds with exit status 2 (failed).
```

Comment: Can you include more logging output? Capistrano should print the command line string of every command before it executes it. It's hard to troubleshoot why a particular command is running slowly without knowing what it is.

Comment: @MattBrictson: I've updated my question with more log output.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first it is important to know that the "No such file or directory" error is benign. Capistrano executes certain commands as tests and takes different code paths based on the results, and it is completely normal that some of those tests result in failures. Unless Capistrano raises an exception, you can safely ignore these "errors".

Second, it seems that `rake assets:precompile` is being run even though you are not using the asset pipeline, and therefore have no use for it. I'm surprised this step could take so long if you don't have any assets, but let's leave that for another discussion.

The quick solution is to not include the asset pipeline steps of the capistrano-rails plugin. As explained in the [README](https://github.com/capistrano/rails#usage), you can do this by including only the steps you need.

So:

```
# Put these in your Capfile
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"

# REMOVE these lines so that asset pipeline steps are excluded
# require "capistrano/rails"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work. Despite not having the assets step commented out in my Capfile, capistrano is still trying to precompile the assets (I'm using  a Rails 5 api app).

Comment: Are you *sure* you aren't requiring either "capistrano/rails" or "capistrano/rails/assets" in your Capfile?

Comment: Oh! what tasks are under capistrano/rails?

Comment: When you load capistrano/rails, you get all behaviors, including assets. This is clearly explained in the [README](https://github.com/capistrano/rails#usage).

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks so much for your help.